# CardLayout tabs overlapping

Tags: java, jpanel, overlay, cardlayout

I have this very simple code of `CardLayout` example. The problem is that when I put in different cards elements such as `JTextFields` or `JTextAreas`, when running Java example those elements overlay on the first card (see screenshot).

When I click switch button, to switch between tabs, the problem disappears (each element is on the card it is supposed to be), but when I run the code for the first time all or some (or none, sometimes it shows it properly) of the `JTextField/Areas` overlap on the front view. Can anyone explain it to me what am I doing wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class temporary{

    CardLayout cards = new CardLayout();
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton switchButton = new JButton("Switch!");



    temporary(){

        JFrame ramka = new JFrame("CardLayout Example");

        topPanel.add(switchButton);
        ListenForButton lForButton = new ListenForButton();
        switchButton.addActionListener(lForButton);


        //panel1
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

        JTextField text1 = new JTextField("TextExample1", 50);
        JTextField text2 = new JTextField(50);
        panel1.add(text1);
        panel1.add(text2);


        //panel2        
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

        JTextField text3 = new JTextField("TextExample2",40);
        panel2.add(text3);

        //panel3
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();

        JTextField text4 = new JTextField("TextExample3", 20);
        panel3.add(text4);

        panel1.setBackground(Color.white);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        panel3.setBackground(Color.gray);

        bottomPanel.add(panel1);
        bottomPanel.add(panel2);
        bottomPanel.add(panel3);

        bottomPanel.setLayout(cards);
        cards.show(bottomPanel, "CardLayout");

        ramka.getContentPane().add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        ramka.getContentPane().add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        ramka.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ramka.setSize(1200, 700);
        ramka.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ramka.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new temporary();
    }

    public class ListenForButton implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            cards.next(bottomPanel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Ubuntu, I'll test in a Mac later, but I prefer to have the `setLayout` call before adding components, try changing it before adding them and see what happens.

Comment: Yep! I think that has resolved the issue! Thanks a lot!